# External linkage

Tags: c++, external, standards, linkage

> $3.5/2- "When a name has external
>   linkage, the entity it denotes can be
>   referred to by names from scopes of
>   other translation units **or** from
>   other scopes of the same translation
>   unit."

Should not the highlighted 'or' be '**and**' or is it just a wrong day for me to interpret some English stuff?

An additional question is if the Standards document (finalized ones) subject to grammatical review by experts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have the same meaning if it said 'and'. It's saying you can do A or B, but choosing one doesn't exclude being able to choose the other (i.e. it's not an exclusive-or).

See [Exclusive "or" in natural language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Exclusive_.E2.80.9Cor.E2.80.9D_in_natural_language).

Summary: the use of "or" in English is quite ambiguous, and its meaning usually arises from context, rather than the word itself. For example:

"You can have tea or coffee" - Here, I can infer that "I can have tea".
"The light is on or off" - Here, I *cannot* infer that "the light is on".

Comment: Oh!. that Exclusive OR in languages is an eye opener for me. I always had that exclusive OR understanding

Comment: Also, "you can have milk or sugar in your coffee" usually means you can have milk and sugar, whereas, "you can have fries or jacket potato with your main" usually means you can't have both (at least, not included in the price).

Answer (score 1):

I think what is meant is inclusive or; that the word "or" should read as the phrase "as well as" or indeed "and". I'm not on the C++ standards committee, but I imagine it's populated by experienced programmers and computer scientists, who know the meaning of "and", "or" and "not".